# Agora Video Call in flutter web cannot run with release

Tags: flutter-web, agora.io

I run the Agora Video call (agora_rtc_engine: 4.1.0-alpha.2) by Flutter with a web platform and debug mode successfully. But when I run with release mode, it is failed: `flutter run -d chrome --release`.

I have an error:

```
Uncaught PlatformException(error, NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'callApi' (k.callApi is not a function), null, null)
```

Please help me with how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the `AgoraRtcWrapper.bundle.js` file in the web folder. You can refer the example code given [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/tree/dev/flutter2)